# Identify component RTC 10800

Tags: identification, rtc

[image]

[image]

I’m a little stuck on this component, it’s on the incoming 230 V supply line to a battery charger circuit, so it should be a surge thermistor, but I can only find types of NTC or PTC, not an RTC.

Any old school folks on here that may know the type/value? It has "10800" printed on it.

Comment: A bigger picture where you can see more than just this one component may help.

Comment: The R is suspect. If this doesn’t exist I’ll assume it’s a PTC with heat marks making it look like a R. What do you think!

Comment: Thanks, I’ll get a bigger picture and whole board ion here tomorrow as it’s a homer for the boss! Would like to fix it for him.

Comment: take it out and see how the VI curve looks? assuming it isn't failed.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the images it looks like an NTC, placed as an inrush limiter. If the black box behind the input connector is a relay then it might be there to short the NTC after start up.

The RTC name on it might be misleading, yes. Google search brought me nothing. So the best way seems to be to take measurements:

- Remove it, and wait for it to cool down
- Attach DMM in resistance measurement mode and record the room-temp resistance
- Apply some heat (ideally, to its body) by a heat gun or at least your soldering iron. Some NTCs response quite fast to human hot breath as well, so you might want to blow fast first to see if its resistance is changing.
- Record its resistance response to heat to see if its a PTC or NTC. I'm 99% sure it's an NTC.

The numbers may mean different things: 10 may mean the diameter (10mm) and 800 may mean 8.00 Ohms. As I said, Google brought me nothing.

PS: By the way, I looked for a varistor first before posting this answer. It appears that it's located to the left of the black box, under the blue cable.

Comment: Thanks to you all for your help, the answer to the numbering is great, I’ve ordered some to see how it goes. Unfortunately the original has a hole burnt in the side so couldn’t measure it. Thank again.